# run script with parameter in cron

Tags: cron, scripting

I want to run .py script:

```
python /home/project/manage.py slope_update
```

If I run it from shell it's OK, but in cron does not work:

```
*/10 * * * * root python /home/project/manage.py slope_update
```

What wrong?

I edit my /etc/crontab file from root

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --repo$
#

*/10 * * * * root /usr/bin/python /home/project/manage.py slope_update
```

With user quanta help:

*/10 * * * * root /usr/bin/python /home/project/manage.py slope_update >> /tmp/foo.log 2>&1

cat foo.log

Unknown command: 'slope_update'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

Why slope_update try to use as command, but must have as parameter
If this "python /home/project/manage.py slope_update" run in terminal it's work. Why?

Comment: "does not work" is worthless for diagnosis.

Comment: script not running but cron work)

Comment: As you have used the /etc/crontab then the root username is required.

Comment: I delete it just now, this is not problem

Comment: do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Redirect the error to file will help you debug easier:

```
*/10 * * * * root python /home/project/manage.py slope_update >> /tmp/foo.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Unknown command: 'slope_update'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
:(

Comment: Why slope_update try to use as command, but must have as parameter

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the full path to python in your crontab e.g.

```
*/10 * * * * root /usr/bin/python /home/project/manage.py slope_update
```

Edit:

The problem will be that the PATH in cron does not include the directory where python is installed (/usr/bin) so you need to supply the full path to python.

Edit Edit:

You are running this from your /etc/crontab ? If not then the root parameter is not required and may be causing problems.

Check email for mail from cron as it sends output from a job to you.

Check where your python lives, `which python` and adjust the path in the crontab accordingly.

Comment: This is not file, it's parameter.

Comment: If I run it from shell it's OK - problem isn't in path to files

Comment: @Konstantin: even if this isn't the problem you're having, `cron` doesn't necessarily run with the same `PATH` that an interactive shell does; you should always specify the full path to be sure.

Comment: doesn't work :(